# Running mvn clean install on a bunch of dir in Linux using bash

Tags: linux, bash, maven

I have 10 projects under my repo dir. I want to write a bash script that runs "mvn clean install" on them one by one. I tried this but doesn't work. Any suggestion ?

```
ls -1 | xargs "mvn -f $1\pom.xml clean install"
```

Comment: I actually found a way to get around it. Here it is.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to use xargs is:

```
ls -1 | xargs -i -- mvn -f '{}/pom.xml' clean install
```

Also, using `find` is better:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec mvn -f '{}/pom.xml' clean install \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it that way:

```
for d in *; do if [[ -d "$d" ]]; then mvn -f "$d/pom.xml" clean install; fi; done
```

Comment: It's also better to add a check: `for d in *; do [[ -d $d ]] && mvn -f "$d/pom.xml" clean install; done`

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 | while read line; do cd $line; mvn clean install; cd ..;done;
```

Comment: Wrap `$line` in double quotes in case of spaces.